# How a worklight(with ionic) project interacts with a gulpfile, package.json node.js bowerc

Tags: node.js, ibm-mobilefirst, gulp, ionic-framework, package.json

I need to develop a mobile application using worklight. While i was going through few sample source code, I observed a gulpfile where they defined few Task/Watch in it. There was also a package.json where they have defined devDependencies property.

I like to know how a hybrid app project (when developed using Worklight or any other tool/framework) use the gulpfile, package.json, node.js, bowerrc. How is the controls passed across all these components when implemented for a hybrid app developmen and What will be the first point of execution in this sequence of execution workflow. As I believe wlEnvInit() inside main.js is the starting point of execution for a worklight project.

I tried google but could'nt find any explanation on the same.

Comment: This is the only other question about using gulp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247211/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-and-mobile-angular-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gulp file you see is part of a default Ionic project. It handles compiling Sass files and running the bower install command to install dependancies. If you are using Sass in your project, then this would be useful to you, but it does not directly relate to MobileFirst.

As you know, when you update your common code, you need to do a build/deploy to get the code deployed to your mobile platforms. So if using Sass, then you need to remember that while the Gulp file may compile the CSS, you still need to "mfp bd" to deploy it to MF.

Does this answer your question?